# When can I attend service (Shabbat) after seminal emission?

Tags: synagogue, sin, sexuality, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, cherem

Unmarried, 22 year old Jewish man here. I've been consciously trying to get myself rid of masturbation for a year now. I started to take precautions and I take this fight very seriously now. I put a calendar in the kitchen and whenever I fail, I put a cross on that particular day. For 2018, I made the following resolution: don't masturbate more than 24 times (or 2 times a month). I got to the point where I average 2 weeks before struggling for real (heart starts pounding, unholy thoughts creeping in, physical 'happenings' throughout my body, absolutely random strong erections on the bus etc.)

I started attending shul about 4 weeks ago. You can't imagine how different everything is if I'm shomer habris for 15+ days or if I go to service just one or two days after I did this aveira. Its too much of an unpleasant topic - the rabbi and daikan are obviously married and I don't feel like bothering them with such an unpleasant topic.

Anyway, after I realized how much I hate myself after failing (it brings forth in me lower feelings of jealousy, envy, lusting and crap like that), I decided to put myself in a ban. I try to avoid human contact for a week. It's always after about 7 days that I feel pure and focused on my prayers instead of toxic thoughts popping up in my head here and there.

I've read on Wikipedia the article on '[keri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keri)', which states that after emission (be it a nocturnal wet dream or regular sex) one should wash his clothes and immerse himself in water.

I remember though that Leviticus (Vayikra) states, that one is impure for 7 days after any kind of emission of that nature.

What do you think? Shabbos is tomorrow and I feel like I shouldn't go – I'm afraid that the same unpleasant things will happen. I feel unholy and not worthy of the community, shaking the hands of others knowing damn well what I did last night.

Im inclined not to go this week, but next week, after being pure for 8 days.

Comment: Keep trying, buddy, it sounds like your heart is in the right place. Read through the entirety of this thread and you will get the answer to your question as well as quite a few strategies to help you. I can personally reccomend the Tikkun Haklali www.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/how-can-i-curb-my-sexual-desire

Comment: Hi Anonymous and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I understand that this is a very sensitive subject, but for practical matters, even sensitive ones like this, one should always [seek advice from his local Orthodox Rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146/9682). For this reason, it’s the site policy not to address such questions - for such an important topic, would you really trust strangers on the Internet over your personal Rabbi who you trust? I wish you much success in finding the answers you seek, and much success in your lofty goal.

Comment: Check out guardyoureyes.com especially the forum and handbook for advice how to stop. Don't despair you can do it.

Comment: @DonielF: It's a bit difficult to bring up this topic on Shabbat table, when the whole community AND the wive of the Daikan (person responsible for the community, not the Rabbi) is present. Sigh, I feel like I have to make this jump into the cold, though.

Comment: @user218076: I was browsing guardureyes.com even back in the day where I had troubles to get past 5 days. Even though I definately noticed progression (especially after I installed the calendar), I still can't get that big breakthrough where I become completely pure. I want to be pure. I want to have a clean mind with holy thoughts, unpolluted by the toxic **** that western society introduced to me. It is as if I'm still missing that one final breakthrough.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This thread can be closed, my question got answered. I feel like the rest is up on me.

Comment: @Anonymous So don’t. Can’t you request a personal meeting with your Rabbi?

Comment: @DonielF: It's not as easy as you think. We are a rather small community, mainly elderly folks from the former Soviet Union. The time schedule is tight and I doubt a married man with many children will take this topic of a young man serious.

Comment: @Anonymous If he’s the Rabbi of your community, he should take any questions any of his congregants have seriously. You won’t know unless you ask.

Comment: Page 63: https://www.scribd.com/doc/111152031/Aryeh-Kaplan-1982-Meditation-and-Kabbalah#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding attending prayer services, the issue is not the ritual impurity. The issue is that [Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezra) promulgated a decree that a ba'al keri (one who had an emission) cannot recite Torah, prayers, etc. However, the Talmud already mentions that the custom was to disregard this decree. This is codified by the great codes of law:

[**Rambam Hilchot Keriat Shema 4:8**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=6&perek=4&halocha=8&hilite=)

> כל הטמאין חייבין בקריאת שמע ומברכין לפניה ולאחריה והן בטומאתן אף על פי
>   שאפשר להן לעלות מטומאתן בו ביום כגון הנוגעין בשרץ או בנדה וזבה ומשכבה
>   וכיוצא בהן ועזרא ובית דינו תקנו שלא יקרא בדברי תורה בעל קרי לבדו
>   והוציאוהו מכלל שאר הטמאין עד שיטבול ולא פשטה תקנה זו בכל ישראל ולא היה
>   כח ברוב הציבור לעמוד בה לפיכך בטלה וכבר נהגו כל ישראל לקרות בתורה
>   ולקרות קריאת שמע והן בעלי קריין לפי שאין דברי תורה מקבלין טומאה אלא
>   עומדין בטהרתן לעולם שנאמר הלא כה דברי כאש נאם יי' מה אש אינה מקבלת
>   טומאה אף דברי תורה אינם מקבלין טומאה
>
> All those ritually impure are obligated to read the Shema and recite
>   the blessings before and after it in their impure state. This applies
>   even when it is possible for them to purify themselves that day -
>   e.g., one who has touched [the carcass of] a שרץ (crawling animal), a
>   menstrual woman, a זבה, or the couch on which these people have laid,
>   and the like.
>
> Ezra and his colleagues decreed that a man who had a seminal emission
>   was forbidden to read the words of the Torah. Thus, they separated him
>   from the other ritually impure until he immersed himself in a mikveh.
>   This ordinance was not universally accepted among the Jewish people.
>   Most were unable to observe it and it was therefore negated.
>
> The Jewish people accepted the custom of reading the Torah and
>   reciting the Shema even after a seminal emission, because the words of
>   Torah cannot contract ritual impurity. Rather, they stand in their
>   state of purity forever, as [Jeremiah 23:29] states: "Are not my words
>   like fire, declares the Lord." Just as fire is incapable of becoming
>   ritually impure, so, too, the words of Torah are never defiled. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912955/jewish/Kriat-Shema-Chapter-Four.htm))

[**Rambam Hilchot Tefilah 4:4**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=558)**-**[**5**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=559)

> כל הטמאין רוחצין ידיהן בלבד כטהורין ומתפללים אע"פ שאפשר להם לטבול
>   ולעלות מטומאתן אין הטבילה מעכבת וכבר בארנו שעזרא תיקן שלא יקרא בעל קרי
>   בלבד בדברי תורה עד שיטבול ובית דין שעמדו אחר כן התקינו אף לתפלה שלא
>   יתפלל בעל קרי בלבד עד שיטבול ולא מפני טומאה וטהרה נגעו בה אלא כדי שלא
>   יהיו תלמידי חכמים מצויים אצל נשותיהן כתרנגולים ומפני זה תקנו טבילה
>   לבעל קרי לבדו והוציאוהו מכלל הטמאין
>
> לפיכך היו אומרין בזמן תקנה זו שאפילו זב שראה קרי ונדה שפלטה שכבת זרע
>   ומשמשת שראתה דם נדה צריכין טבילה לקריאת שמע וכן לתפלה מפני הקרי אף על
>   פי שהם טמאין וכן הדין נותן שאין טבילה זו מפני טהרה אלא מפני הגזירה שלא
>   יהיו מצויין אצל נשותיהן תמיד וכבר בטלה גם תקנה זו של תפלה לפי שלא פשטה
>   בכל ישראל ולא היה כח בציבור לעמוד בה
>
> All the ritually impure need only wash their hands in order to pray,
>   just like those not in such a state. Even if they are able to immerse
>   themselves [in a mikveh] and ascend from their impure state, this
>   immersion is not required [for prayer].
>
> We have already explained that Ezra decreed that only one who has had
>   a seminal emission is prohibited from Torah study until he has
>   immersed himself. The Rabbinical Court [that existed afterwards]
>   decreed that [this applies] even to prayer, i.e., such a person alone
>   should not pray until he immerses himself.
>
> These decrees were not put into effect because of questions of ritual
>   purity and impurity, but rather to ensure that the Torah scholars
>   would not overindulge in marital intimacy with their wives. Therefore,
>   they instituted ritual immersion only for one who has a seminal
>   emission, thereby excepting him from the other ritually impure.
>
> Therefore, at the time of this decree, it was said that even a זב who
>   had a seminal emission, a menstruating woman who emitted semen, and a
>   woman who saw traces of menstrual blood after relations, required
>   immersion to recite the Shema and to pray because of the seminal
>   emission, despite [the fact that they remained] ritually impure.
>
> This is reasonable, since this immersion was not a matter of purity,
>   but a result of the decree so that they would not constantly be with
>   their wives.
>
> This decree regarding prayer was also abolished, since it was not
>   universally accepted by the Jewish people, and the community at large
>   was unable to observe it. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920166/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Four.htm))

[R. Yaakov Ben Asher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher) cites many earlier opinions on the matter and concludes that the custom is not to prevent any prayer,  Shema, or Torah on account of seminal emissions:

**[Tur O.C. Siman 86](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x200)**

> כל הטמאין קורין בתורה וקורין שמע ומתפללין חוץ מבעל קרי שבא מקלות ראש
>   לכך אסור בד"ת ובק"ש ובתפלה והאידנא שרי דאמר רב נחמן בר יצחק נהוג עלמא
>   כר"י בן בתירא בד"ת דאמר ד"ת אין מקבלין טומאה וא"צ טבילה וכן כי אתא
>   זעירי אמר בטלוה לטבילותא כר"י ב"ב ולאו דוקא לטבילותא אלא הוא הדין נמי
>   רחיצה בט' קבין לא בעי דהא ר"י לא מצריך אפילו רחיצה וקאמר דנהוג עלמא
>   כוותיה לגמרי כתב רב אלפס איכא מ"ד הא דאמר בטלו לטבילותא בין לד"ת בין
>   לק"ש ותפלה ואיכא למ"ד דוקא לד"ת אבל לתפלה בעי טבילה ולאו דוקא טבילה
>   אלא רחיצה בט' קבין ורבינו האי ז"ל כתב כיון דבגמרא ליכא האי מילתא בהדיא
>   נקוט מנהג כל ישראל בידך שבעלי קריין אע"פ שאין להם מים אינן מתפללין עד
>   שירחצו וה"ר ישעיה כתב שאין חילוק בין ק"ש לתפלה וכ"כ בה"ג והשתא נהוג
>   עלמא דקרי בעל קרי בתורה בק"ש ותפלה ויורד לפני התיבה קמי טבילה ונראה
>   כיון דתלי במנהגא אזלינן בכל דוכתא בתר מנהגא דנהיגי ביה והאידנא לא נהוג
>   בטבילה ולא ברחיצה לא לד"ת וק"ש ולא לתפלה וכ"כ הראב"ד לא נהוג עלמא כר"י
>   אלא בטבילה אבל ברחיצה לא נהוג כותיה וזעירי מצריך ט' קבין ומיהו בכל
>   מקומותינו לא נהוג  כותיה אף בט' קבין וסמכו על הירושלמי דגרסינן התם גבי
>   יוה"כ אסור בתשמיש המטה השתא ברחיצה אסור בתשמיש לכ"ש כלומר אסור לו
>   להתפלל בעודו בעל קרי עד שיטבול וכיון שאסור ברחיצה כ"ש בתשמיש המטה
>   ומשני במקום שאין טובלין ואם איתא שצריך ט' קבין מאי משני אכתי ברחיצה
>   אסור כ"ש בתה"מ

[R. Yosef Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) codifies this law, stating that now the custom is to not prevent anything on account of seminal emissions:

[**Shulchan Aruch O.C. 88:1**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x454)

> כל הטמאים קורין בתורה וקורין ק"ש ומתפללין חוץ מבעלי קרי שהוציאו עזרא
>   מכל הטמאים ואסרו בין בד"ת בין בק"ש ותפלה עד שיטבול כדי שלא יהיו ת"ח
>   מצויין אצל נשותיהן כתרנגולין ואח"כ בטלו  אותה תקנה והעמידו הדבר על
>   הדין שאף בעל קרי מותר בד"ת ובקריאת שמע  ובתפלה בלא טבילה ובלא רחיצה
>   דתשעה קבין וכן פשט המנהג

[R. Mordechai Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe), in his codification, writes that the decree was annulled, and such is the custom across the entire world:

**[Levush O.C. 88:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14586&st=&pgnum=57)**

> לפיכך כל הטמאים קורין בתורה וקורין קריאת שמע ומתפללין חוץ מבעל קרי
>   שהוציאו עזרא בתקנותיו מכלל שאר הטמאים וגזר שיהא אסור בדברי תורה ובין
>   בקריאת שמע ובין בתפלה עד שיטבול וטעמו היה כדי שלא יהיו תלמידי חכמים
>   נוהגין קלות ראש בעצמן ויהיו מצויין אצל נשותיהן כתרנגולים שמתוך גזירה
>   זו יפרשו מנשותיהם כי ירע בעיניהם לפרוש כל יום מדברי תורה וקריאת שמע
>   ותפלה ואח"כ כשראו שגם בזה לא היו יכולין לעמוד בטלו אותה תקנה והעמידו
>   הדבר על הדין שאף בעל קרי מותר בדברי תורה ובקריאת שמע ובתפלה בלא טבילה
>   ובלא רחיצה דתשעה קבין וכן פשט המנהג בכל העולם

[R. Yechiel Michel Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein) explains that the decree was annulled but he points out that it was not the Sages that annulled it, but the people annulled it and the Sages merely gave their approval. Therefore some people continue to immerse to this day, even though the custom has spread that it is unnecessary. He also quotes several opinions about the extent of the decree and its annullment but concludes that the great poskim ruled it annulled for everything:

**[Aruch Hashulchan O.C. 88:1-3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=154&hilite=)**

> כתב הרמב"ם סוף הל' ק"ש [פ"ד הל' ח'] כל הטמאין חייבין בק"ש ומברכין
>   לפניה ולאחריה והן בטומאתן אע"פ שאפשר להן לעלות מטומאתן בו ביום כגון
>   הנוגעין בשרץ או בנדה וזבה וכיוצא בהן ועזרא ובית דינו תקנו שלא יקרא
>   בדברי תורה בעלי קרי לבדו והוציאוהו מכלל שאר הטמאין עד שיטבול ולא פשטה
>   תקנה זו בכל ישראל ולא היה כח ברוב הצבור לעמוד בה לפיכך בטלה וכבר נהגו
>   כל ישראל לקרות בתורה ולקרות ק"ש והן בעלי קריין לפי שאין דברי תורה
>   מקבלין טומאה שנאמר [ירמיה כג, כט] הלא כה דברי כאש נאום ה' מה אש אינו
>   מקבל טומאה אף ד"ת אינו מקבל טומאה עכ"ל
>
> והטעם שעזרא תקן טבילה לבעלי קרי מפני שבא מקלות ראש [טור] ועוד כדי שלא
>   יהיו ת"ח מצוים אצל נשותיהם כתרנגולים [גמרא כ"ב.] ומדברי הרמב"ם נראה
>   שלא החכמים ביטלוה אלא מאליה נבטלה מפני שלא יכלו לעמוד בתקנה זו וכן
>   משמע מלשון הגמרא שם דאמר נהוג עלמא וכו' ואף ע"ג דאמר שם בטלוה לטבילותא
>   י"ל שאחר שנהגו כן חיזקו חכמים דבר זה ולכן מצינו במשניות שנהגו בתקנה זו
>   לפי שעדיין לא נבטלה וגם עכשיו יש מהדרים ששומרים לטבול לקירויין ואין זה
>   כעובר על תקנת חכמים שצוו לבטלה דבאמת לא החכמים גזרו לבטלה שהעם מעצמן
>   נהגו כן נתפשטה התקנה והחכמים הסכימו לזה משום ביטול תורה ומשום ביטול
>   פריה ורביה לפיכך גם עתה יכולין להחמיר בטבילה זו ובלבד שלא יעבור בשביל
>   זה זמן ק"ש או תפלה בצבור והרמב"ם בתשו' העיד על עצמו שמימיו לא ביטל
>   טבילה זו
>
> כתבו רבותינו בעלי התוספות שם דיש מפרשים דרק לתורה בטלוה ולא לתפלה ור"י
>   פי' דלא שנא ע"ש וכ"כ הרמב"ם והרא"ש וכל הפוסקים ויש מהגאונים שאמרו דנהי
>   דבטלו לטבילותא מ"מ רחיצה בתשעה קבין צריך ורבותינו הפוסקים חלקו על זה
>   כמ"ש הטור דא"צ לא טבילה ולא רחיצה בט' קבין וטבילה זו אפילו בשאובין
>   כדאיתא פ"ח דמקואות ואפילו לפי תקנת עזרא אינו אלא בקרי גמור היורה כחץ
>   אבל ראה מים חלוקים א"צ טבילה גם לפי התקנה [מג"א סק"א] ותשעה קבין הוא
>   דוקא מג' כלים לא יותר ולא יפסיק משפיכת הראשון עד שיתחיל בהשני וכן
>   מהשני לשלישי [ט"ז סק"א

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alex! Did I got it right: It's alright to go to shul and attend the Parshah lesson, the following Shabbat prayer and the meal as long as I don't verbally say any word, including the 'Amen' or 'Brechu'? According to Ezra, anyways. The Talmudic resource states that the decree was put forth in order to not let the Rabbi overindulge in marital relations, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @Anonymous According to Ezra's original decree you would be limited in what holy recitations you could partake in; however, the greatest codes of Jewish Law cited above all allow you to partake in everything - prayers, Shema, Torah, etc.

Comment: @Anonymous and since you're allowed to, you're REQUIRED to say at least the mandatory things (shema, shemoneh esrei, etc.).  It's possible to quibble about what exactly is mandatory, but it's 100% not worth it.

Comment: I see. You didn't mention the chapter in Vakriyah (Leviticus) which talks about purity, though. If I remember correctly, one who had emissions, is unclean for 7 days (oddly enough the time I need to be 'on' again after failing) and should put a tent outside of the main camp. Of course this is a bit difficult in todays world, but I feel like it's talking about isolating oneself for this period of time. You talked about Ezra's decree and the Talmudic counterargument. What about the source of it all, though?

Comment: @Anonymous the camp in this context refers to the Temple Mount.  As long as you don't go up there, you're fine.  Please, please speak to a Rabbi.  And if this is affecting your mental health, speak to a psychologist (first!).

Comment: @Anonymous See Leviticus 15:16 about seminal emissions. וְאִישׁ כִּי תֵצֵא מִמֶּנּוּ שִׁכְבַת זָרַע וְרָחַץ בַּמַּיִם אֶת כָּל בְּשָׂרוֹ וְטָמֵא עַד הָעָרֶב  *And if the flow of seed go out from a man, then he shall bathe all his flesh in water, and be unclean until the even.* Even so, as I mentioned in the answer the impurity is not the issue.

Comment: Look around Berakhot 21b

Answer (score 7):

The problem, as I understand it, is that your struggle is causing you to be distanced from normal, healthy mitzva behavior. [Dr. Yocheved Debow writes about this phenomenon in her guide for educators.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1602802203). While understandable -- and driven by a lot of negative emotions -- it's probably not the best track to take.

The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch actually writes (151:7)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49256&st=&pgnum=198) that the appropriate response to a setback in this area is to get *more*, not *less* involved -- to receive an *aliyah* in synagogue, to read the Torah, to be *one of the first ten people in synagogue*, to bake matza, and the like.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Alex has more sources, but https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.3.7

Comment: @Anonymous you need to talk to a human being!  A Rabbi, a psychologist, or a close friend.  People on the internet are of limited use here.