# Being with a non Jew

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, family-members, reincarnation

I’ve read on this site that teshuva fixes all sins except the ones done between you and someone else, like stealing someone’s shoe for example.

If teshuva does work, will that take away her soul which is connected to yours and take away the severe punishments when one passes away? Also does it take away the part one is reincarnated into a dog?

PLEASE DO NOT DELETE MY FELLOW YIDIN IM ASKING THESE QUESTIONS BECAUSE THE OTHER ONES SIMILAR DIDNT FULLY ANSWER THESE TO AN EXTENT.

Comment: I see where you head with your questions and that's not the mainstream of Judaism. **Mystics and superstition you ask about are not the "know-how" of our tradition but only speculations**. Many ideas (such as reincarnation into animals or plants) are not real and only aim to frighten or terrify a person but not really exist. As a newcomer, I would advise you to turn to the Jewish Halachah, which is the mainstream study and you'll feel much much better B"H.

Comment: The assumption that the Teshuvah fixes sins is theoretical only - you may never know if a sin is forgiven until G-d testifies that. And you're probably not a prophet. I would reccomend  to familiarize yourself with Rambam's Laws of Teshuva here: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911888/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-One.htm and come back to re-ask your question

Comment: Who's soul and what sexuality your question is about?

Comment: @AlBerko Where do you see in Rambam's laws of teshuva that you never know if a sin is forgiven until God testifies to it? Chapter 2 implies otherwise

Comment: @ba **"ויעיד עליו יודע תעלומות שלא ישוב לזה החטא לעולם**, שנאמר "ולא נאמר עוד אלוהינו, למעשה ידינו--אשר בך, ירוחם יתום" (הושע יד,ד).

Comment: Thank you this has to do with me Chas veshalom if it should ever happen again being with a non Jewish girl with intercourse even during it I was repenting for what I was doing and after it I’ve decided to learn everyday for 1 hour for one year straight I’m just scared. I will become a whole different person spiritually and emotionally a better Ben Torah hopefully that will be enough for teshuva so my soul won’t be attached to hers and about reincarnation as you’ve said I don’t know if it’s true, but hopefully not. The rabbis seem like they know what they’re saying that’s all.

Comment: Even the source cited on this site about reincarnation into a dog doesn't say that. Sha'ar Ruach HaKodesh siman 20 doesn't at all talk about sex with a genitle. Some folks are making up fake Torah news

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify -- if one wronged another person, then one must apologize to them as part of teshuva. Consensual behavior, however, would not require their apology.

The answer is yes -- teshuva works. Rav Moshe Feinstein has a couple of responsa starting OC4:117 about teshuva for various intimate acts; the common theme to them is "yes it was a sin; you should regret it, stop doing it [and avoid situations where you're tempted or triggered], confess it to God, and commit to do better; maybe fast once a month for a few months and say some extra Psalms if you can. But any exaggerated language about automatically wiping out your soul, or worse than all other sins or whatnot -- aren't literal." Rambam's Laws of Teshuva, similarly, has a bunch of categories of sins and their punishments; none of this reincarnation and the like stuff. (He also acknowledges that some texts exaggerated the punishment for certain acts; they meant "if you do this habitually", not if it happened once and the person repented.)

I'd heard an Orthodox psychologist at an OU event mention a similar point -- a lot of people tell them they feel so guilty that they believe teshuva won't work; he points out to them that starts to sound like another religion. We have laws that we follow, and those include teshuva.

[As discussed on a similar matter](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93451/21), while sincere regret is required, the goal needs to be to get *more* involved in Torah and mitzvos, not less; someone who is so paralyzed by guilt of their past that they don't go to synagogue, for example, is just compounding their problem.

*Pischei Teshuva* YD1:6 tells of a kosher butcher who wants to confess to a rabbi on his deathbed: *Rabbi ... there was once a non-Jewish woman ... and unrelated to that ... I had a drinking problem; sometimes I was drunk when slaughtering animals and didn't use the right kosher technique.* The rabbis agonize about that second half of the confession -- what do we now tell all the people who bought meat from this fellow, and are their dishes kosher? The first half of the confession gets no discussion at all.

(Don't get me wrong -- it is wrong and don't do it! But if someone sincerely repented about it, they have to move forward.)

Comment: It’s not about the fall... it’s about the getting up!

Comment: Thank you this has to do with me Chas veshalom if it should ever happen again being with a non Jewish girl with intercourse even during it I was repenting for what I was doing and after it I’ve decided to learn everyday for 1 hour for one year straight I’m just scared